# XPS M1730 Freezing & Crashing unexpectedly

Tags: windows-7, freeze, crash, dell-xps

I have a Dell XPS M1730, freshly installed with Windows 7 Professional 32-bit that every so often crashes completely unexpectedly. It need not be running any applications at all for this to happen, never mind anything particularly intensive. It also clearly is not a BSoD issue as no Minidump files are being created in the process. All drivers are up to date and have been both rolled back and then updated and the Device Manager reports no issues. There are very few applications installed on the machine and it has only been online once. It runs a minimal boot of Win7 and yet still after all of this something is making it crash. All of this suggests to me it may be more like a hardware problem but to be honest I really have no idea - so I thought I'd try here.

Any thoughts...?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Does the event log show anything? It may contain errors that preceded the crash or details of what caused it after rebooting.

Comment: Unfortunately not, there are various events but nothing with a 'warning' or 'error' level that would suggest a crash...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a thermal problem.  Is it well-ventilated?  Are all the fans running and clear of dust?  Will the machine reboot immediately after a crash?  There are a few other possibilities (failing memory, processor) but I'd look into this first.

Comment: Stupidly, that wasn't something that had immediately occured to me. I immediately had ran the CPUID temperature monitor and nothing had seemed unusual so I had almost forgotten that as an explanation. I shall check & see...

Comment: Hmmm... I checked this but all seems to be fine in the cooling dept. so I resorted a fresh install of Win7 and all new hardware drivers. Seems to be OK (holds breath)...

Comment: Thankyou much for the suggestion though

Comment: @james clark - No problem.  It's a weird issue...I'm curious to see if it stays stable.  Just seems awfully weird to have been a software problem...

Answer (score 1):

I has the same problem.  Playing a game on my m1730 with the 8700 sli setup.  I have gone to nVidea and upgraded my graphics drivers and every other driver I could then the problem started.  I had no overclocking and sli disabled.  I then went back to Dell and re- installed the original crap driver from 2008 I believe.  The problem hasn't occured since.  I dust my system regularly so it isn't dust.  Could be an overheating issue because when I installed the new graphics drivers the fans would speed up and slow down constantly, very noisy.  I hate to go backwards with drivers, but this one seems to work.  Never again am I going to buy a crappy laptop, desktops are where its at.

Answer (score 1):

The fans issue is not your graphics driver.  It's your BIOS upgrade-you have A11.  Go back to A10 and the fan nonsense stops.